# Explain the proof behind maximal ideals $\iff $ quotient is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

> $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $M$ is a maximal ideal $\iff$ $R/M$ is a field.

[Proof is here](http://prntscr.com/cduq5t)

1. Can someone explain the inclusion $J \subset \ker \psi$?
2. Can someone also explain the hypothesis that

> To see this note that if for all $r \in R$, there is some $r_1 \in J$ such that $$\psi(r) = \psi(r_1)$$

Sorry but where did this hypothesis come from and why are we assuming this to prove $J = R$?

[Proof is here](http://prntscr.com/cdv1et)

3. Can someoene explain the statement

> This ideal $\psi^{-1}(r + M)$ contains $M$ because $r \in \psi^{-1}(r+M)$.

Isn't the definition of the preimage of $r+M$ just $$\psi^{-1}(r+M) = \{r \in R : \psi(r) = r +M \}$$

I mean I could just prove the inclusion, but such an attempt won't really reveal what the statement's intent.

($x \in M$, $\psi(x) = x + M = M$)

Answer (score 1):

$1.$ $0+M$ is the zero of $R/M$. So $\psi(J)=0+M$ implies $J\subset ker(\psi)$.

$2.$ Since $\psi(J)=R/M$, then for all $r\in R$, we have $$\psi(r)=r+M\in\psi(J),$$thus there exists $r_1\in J$ such that $$\psi(r_1)=r+M=\psi(r).$$ Here, $\psi(r-r_1)=0+M$ and so $r-r_1\in M$, i.e., $r-r_1=m$, where $m\in M$. Therefore $$r=r_1+m\in J+M\subseteq J$$ Since $r$ is arbitrary, it follows that $R\subseteq J$.

$3.$ $\psi^{-1}(r+M)=\{s\in R:\psi(s)=s+M=r+M\}$.

Comment: 1. Not entirely understanding you, 2. "thus there exists $r_1$.." okay...but why the first equality $\psi(r_1) = r + M$? 3. You didn't explain my question...

Comment: 1. For all $x\in J$, $\psi(x)=x+M=0+M$, so $x\in ker(\psi)$. 2. By definition of $\psi$, $\psi(r)=r+M$; since $\psi(r)\in\psi(J)$, there exists $r_1\in J$ such that $\psi(r)=\psi(r_1)$. Hence $\psi(r_1)=r+M$. 3. I corrected your text. Why is $\psi^{-1}(r+M)$ ideal?

Comment: 1. That's a very silly statement (from the proof, not you) considering any map $f: V \to W$ yields $ker(f) \subset V$. 3. I know you did, $\psi^{-1}$ is an ideal because $<r+M>$ is an ideal.

Comment: 1. Sorry, but I'm not understanding your question. I think my argument is already satisfactory. 3. $Since M=ker(\psi)$, then $\psi(M)=0+M\in<r+M>$. Thus $M=\psi^{-1}(\psi(M))\subseteq\psi^{-1}(r+M)$.

Comment: 1. It is, I am commenting on the original answer in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Q1.

Let $j\in J$.

$\psi(j)=0+M$ since $\psi(J)=0+M$.

This means $j\in\ker\psi$.

So $J\subseteq\ker\psi$.

Q2. Note that $\psi(J)=R/M$ implies that $R/M\subseteq \psi(J)$.

So any $r+M=\psi(r_1)$ for some $r_1\in J$.

Q3. For Q3 the keyword is "properly".

To see the ideal $\psi^{-1}(r+M)$ contains $M$, take $m\in M$.

$\psi(m)=m+M=M\subseteq (r+M)$ since every ideal contains zero and zero in $R/M$ is $M$. (Do you know this? Comment below if you need details.)

As mentioned, this is not really the main point. The keyword is "properly". This follows from the fact that $r\notin M$ but $r\in\psi^{-1}(r+M)$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks

Comment: Certainly, $M \subset r + M$ since we can take $r = e_R.$

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to go in order here.

The first point that's somewhat brushed under the rug here is that if $R, S$ are commutative rings, $\phi: R \to S$ is surjective, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $\phi(I)$ is an ideal of $S$. To see this, note that if $s \in S$, then $s = \phi(r)$ for some $r \in R$, so 
\begin{equation}
\phi(r')s = \phi(r')\phi(r) = \phi(rr') \subset \phi(R)
\end{equation}

Then, one uses the fact that a field has only two ideals, and we examine each case individually; $\phi(J) = 0 \subset R/M$, and $\phi(J) = R/M$.

It seems like you feel comfortable with the first case, $\phi(J) = 0$.

For the second case, we $\textbf{assume}$ the map is surjective (as we have handled the other case in which it is not), and so the statement that $\phi(r_1) = r + M$ for some $r_1 \in J$ is precisely this surjectivity.

I think the proof of the converse is perhaps too complicated. One can show that if $R$ is a commutative ring with unity, $R$ is a field $\textbf{if and only if}$ $R$ has precisely two ideals. It turns out that the ideals of $R/M$ are precisely the images of the ideals of $R$ containing $M$ under the quotient map. To prove this, start with the fact that the pre-images of ideals are ideals and examine ideals of $R/M$.

Once you've established that, the result follows easily. Since $M$ is maximal, there are only two such ideals, $\phi(R)$ and $\phi(M)$.

Comment: Uh I am not comfortable with the first case, that's why I am asking the inclusion of the kernel.